# Beginner Django: Python ImportError and ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

im practising using Django/Python to make a blog. It has been going well but got stuck recently with Two errors, the first has gone now but comes back when I move things around. the second is the current error with the current state.

```
djangogirls/mysite/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'mysite'
```

current error:

```
djangogirls/blog/views.py", line 4, in <module>
from forms import PostForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'
```

Here are some of my files:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


# Create your views here.



def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

Not completely sure about the structures yet (very beginner), so any advice would be so appreciated

Comment: Are both forms.py and views.py in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

add . before forms... just like you are importing from .models the Post model, import from .forms.